# Use readonly and invisible in 1 field openerp

Tags: odoo

How to use readonly and invisible in 1 field using attrs in openerp ?Just likes I have field 'country'. I want this field read only if a==b and invisible if c==d .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes on fields:

```
<... attrs = "{'readonly': [('field_a','=','field_b')],'invisible':[('field_c','=','field_d')]}" .../>
```

Please provide some more information about what `a,b,c` and `d` are.

Comment: It's worked. Thanks :)) .a,b,c and d are some states in my workflow :)